# Understanding How SBT, Scala, SBT-Idea and Play Framework Work Together

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-idea

I am new and had built some simple Scala applications / tutorials using SBT. I move on to Play framework and generated an empty project using `g8 typesafehub/play-scala`. I did a few tests to make sure it was properly generated. That checked out good and I added sbt-idea plugin, `https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea`, to generate an IntelliJ project. This is where the hell broke loose.

I had to find the right Scala, SBT, Play framework and sbt-idea versions combinations to get it compiled perfectly. Otherwise, the compilation would broke with out right errors or warnings that got me guessing. So far, the best "combination" I had was

```
Scala 2.9.2 
Play 2.0.1 
SBT 0.11.2 
sbt-idea 1.1.0
```

with the following warning

```
 [warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] maven-plugins#maven-cobertura-plugin;1.3!maven-cobertura-plugin.plugin (282ms)
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/maven-plugins/maven-cobertura-plugin/1.3/maven-cobertura-plugin-1.3.plugin
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] maven-plugins#maven-findbugs-plugin;1.3.1!maven-findbugs-plugin.plugin (284ms)
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/maven-plugins/maven-findbugs-plugin/1.3.1/maven-findbugs-plugin-1.3.1.plugin
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: maven-plugins#maven-cobertura-plugin;1.3!maven-cobertura-plugin.plugin
[warn]  :: maven-plugins#maven-findbugs-plugin;1.3.1!maven-findbugs-plugin.plugin
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

If I use the latest versions, SBT 0.12 and Play 2.0.3 I would get a complilating error. Any idea or explanation how I can get all these works together nicely? It is a version mess to me right now. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you should start with Play from the original site: http://www.playframework.org/ you'll find there newest stable version for download (currently it's 2.0.3).

It contains proper dependencies and its installation is as easy as unpacking the ZIP and exporting the path as described in: [Installing](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/Installing) doc.

I can ensure you that this approach is the easiest and most sure way, it works as expected, creates proper IntelliJ projects etc. If I'm not wrong IntelliJ support was fixed after 2.0.1 also other indices had some improvements, so there is no sense to fight with 2.0.1 if it isn't really required.

Comment: I agreed. After I posted this and took a short break, I realized that play uses sbt as its management console. It seems that I don't need sbt-idea at all. play actually has intellij project generator built-in. I seriously think I have confused play with sbt-idea plugin :( Good, I can get back to play.